# How to pass multi datatables to a stored procedure using C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two table types in SQL Server 2008 R2.

- `transTable` with `transDate, transTime, invoiceId, invoiceDesc` columns
- `transItemTable` with `staffId, price, quantity` columns

I created a rollback stored procedure and use both table types as parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TransInInsert
(
    @dt AS transTable READONLY,
    @dt2 AS transItemTable READONLY
)
AS
    DECLARE @transId int

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO transIn (transDate, transTime, invoiceId, invoiceDesc)
            SELECT 
                transDate, transTime, invoiceId, invoiceDesc 
            FROM @dt

        SET @transId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO transInStaff (transId, staffId, price, quantity)
            SELECT 
                @transId, staffId, price, quantity 
            FROM @dt2
    COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    /*************************************
    *  Get the Error Message for @@Error
    *************************************/
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
```

The relation of `transIn` and `transInStaff` tables is here:

[image: relation of transIn and transInStaff tables]

I want to insert data in both table using rollback because of sensitive and related data. So I make a code in c# and made data in DataTable format and prepare them to send into the stored procedure:

```
DataTable dtTrans = new DataTable();
dtTrans.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] {
                             new DataColumn("transDate", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("transTime", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("invoiceId", typeof(string)),
                             new DataColumn("invoiceDesc", typeof(string))});

DateTime dt = (DateTime)dtp.Value;
string transDate = clsEasy.makeDateToPersian(dt);
string transTime = clsEasy.makeTime7(DateTime.Now);
string invoiceId = txtInvoiceNumber.Text;
string invoiceDesc = txtDescription.Text;

dtTrans.Rows.Add(transDate, transTime, invoiceId, invoiceDesc);

DataTable dtTransItems = new DataTable();
dtTransItems.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { 
                                  new DataColumn("staffId", typeof(string)),
                                  new DataColumn("price", typeof(string)),
                                  new DataColumn("quantity", typeof(string))});

 for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      string staffId = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      string price = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
      string quantity = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

      dtTransItems.Rows.Add(staffId, price, quantity);
 }

 int result = cls.executeDataTable("TransInInsert","@dt", dtTrans);
```

I can send one of tables using this method:

```
protected int executeDataTable(string spName,string tableName, DataTable dt)
{
    try
    {
        connect();
        int affect = 0;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(tableName, dt);

        affect = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        disconnect();
        return affect;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        disconnect();
        return ex.Number * (-1);
    }
}
```

But I want send both DataTables to SQL Server. How can I to do that?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It just seems to me that just using SQL directly from code, or better, an ORM would result in many times less code to write and maintain.